# How to make small value exponentials default to zero?

Tags: numerics

I have a function `f[t_] := Exp[N[-(t - 30.)*(t - 30)/100]]`. When I tried to evaluate `f[600]` it shows `Exp[-3294] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision
may be lost.` Is there a global setting to make such an evaluation default to zero?

Currently my implementation is: `f[t_] := If[t < 70, Exp[N[-(t - 30.)*(t - 30)/100]], 0]` But I am hoping to have way to set up globally.

Comment: The output is already zero, isn't it? The warning is merely a warning, don't be afraid of it.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be

```
   f1[t_] :=  Quiet@Check[Exp[N[-(t - 30.)*(t - 30)/100]], 0, General::munfl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

reference https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/munfl.html

Comment: I found that by compiling the number, `Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Exp[x]][-3924]` it will default to 0.